# issue: sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: ubuntu

my system is ubuntu 16.04. i just want to make a test. i was login with my general account haungxin. i run commnad `sudo chown huangxin:huangxin sudo`,then run sudo show this error. and continue i run `su root` & `chown root:root sudo`,i checked the property of sudo file is `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 136808 2月   1 02:37 /usr/bin/sudo` . but when i run sudo in general accout , it also dump error: sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set  , i don't know why that happend  i have  recoverd sudo file's property as previous and i can't find different compare to other machines's sudo file property . but why it can't work as normal. that's really confused me. i will really preciated who can it.

Comment: I think this post will help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set

Comment: i have seen this before , and i used to think just changed back the property of sudo file  would be work. as you seee , my sudo file  is recovered as property '-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 136808 2月   1 02:37 /usr/bin/sudo' , but is still have problem , i tried reboot my machine and not work.  it's really strange , i don't know what's wrong with it. i just change `chown [user:user] /usr/bin/sudo ` and then log to root user to recovery it `chown  root:root /usr/bin/sudo`.   i have searched similar issues before and  i see others issue solved by recoevery sudo file to root:root .

Comment: but it doesn't work for me , i absolutely have no idea about it.

Comment: i solved it by chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo. and now ls -la /usr/bin/sudo is '-rwsr-xr-x' and before is '-rwxr-xr-x'.  i was too careless to focus this different with other machines sudo file and  i am not familiar with this property meaning.  finally i solved the issue , thank you very much .